# Doubt related to offchain

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I know that offchain means the logic is stored out side of blockchain. So a contract is deployed to the onchain, and my **offchain logic can't be in the contract**, if it is in contract then it will be onchain as the contract will be deployed to onchain eventually. For example the logic could be in jsx file, right?? correct me if i am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to implement off-chain logic with on-chain smart contracts is through the use of oracle services. Oracles act as intermediaries between the blockchain and external systems, allowing off-chain data to be incorporated into on-chain smart contracts. This can be done by having the smart contract call out to an oracle service, which retrieves the off-chain data and provides it to the smart contract.

Another way to implement off-chain logic with smart contracts is to use a layer 2 solution such as state channels or sidechains. These solutions allow for more complex off-chain logic to be performed, with the results being periodically reconciled on-chain.

In terms of the specific example you mentioned, JSX (JavaScript XML) is typically used in the context of web development, and would not typically be used for implementing off-chain logic for smart contracts. However, you could potentially use other programming languages or frameworks such as JavaScript or Python to write off-chain logic that interacts with on-chain smart contracts.

Comment: is multisig  a state channel?